# Assigning static ports in windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, .net

I am having an issue with a port needed by an application sometimes being taken by another application, I have added the following to the registry assuming this will exclude the port from the dynamically assign ports:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
ReservedPorts = xxxxx-xxxxx

Is it possible to check a range of dynamic ports that may be excluded and it there another way to reserve this port by OS that only the specific application can use.

Comment: This should work as you intended. Did you enter ReservedPorts as Multi-string Value and rebooted? Values should be between 1025 and 5000 unless you changed MaxUserPort setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That registry setting allows you to prevent a port from being used as an ephemeral port. It doesn't prevent an application from binding to that port explicitly (as long as no other process already has it bound).

Comment: Hi Evan, is there a way to block access to the port by another application, or is it pot luck.

Comment: There is no "blocking access" to a port in Windows. Your best resolution is to figure out what program is binding to the port you need to be free (probably using `netstat -a -o` and looking the PID), then altering the startup order until the program that is supposed to bind first gets to.